# php connect to sql local server

Tags: php, mysql

I 'm trying to connect to mysql local server ,but mysql_select_db function return false when I select first_try_books database .

```
      <?php
 $conn=mysql_connect();
 if($conn) print("Connect Successfully");
 else {echo "error in connection ... try again "; die();}
if( mysql_select_db("first_try_books",$conn))
    print("select Successfully");
else
    print("error select");  
if( $tab=mysql_query("SELECT book_id FROM lib",$conn))
    print("query Successfully");

      ?><!-- end PHP script -->
```

[this is the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgR5n.png)

Comment: try to see what the error is.  `mysql_select_db("first_try_books",$conn) or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: [don't use `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/1028804)

Comment: First get your `mysql_connect()` correctly coded RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php it has parameters that are rather important. Also Please dont use the `mysql_` database extensions, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: @roullie the error is Access denied for user ''@'local host' to database 'first_try_books'

Comment: See my previous comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok,I'll do that .thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a different driver to connect to your BD?

you can use PDO

```
$SQL= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data_base','user','pass');
```

or mysqli

```
$SQL= new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','data_base');
```